# Can we state that math.floor(x) == int(x) are similar?

Tags: python

When I want to convert a float to an integer value I have the options `math.floor` or casting it to `int`, both results are the same.

**Performance:**: `int` seems to be `30%` faster

```
def floorTest():
    [math.floor(float(i)) for i in range(10)]
def intTest():
    [int(float(i)) for i in range(10)]

import timeit
print(timeit.timeit(stmt='floorTest()', setup='from __main__ import floorTest', number=10**7))
print(timeit.timeit(stmt='intTest()', setup='from __main__ import intTest', number=10**7))
```

**Disassembler:** I'm not going to paste the outcome, as they are the same for both `floorTest` and `intTest` from the aforementioned Performance test.

Now the Question:

> Can we say `math.floor()` has the same effect as casting a float to `int`?

The reason I'm asking is, that i might be overseeing some points.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, `int` and `math.floor` have different behaviour:

```
>>> import math
>>> f = 1.23456
>>> int(f)
1
>>> int(-f)
-1
>>> math.floor(f)
1
>>> math.floor(-f)
-2
```